# How to bash command output that isn't STDOUT from babel shell command

Tags: org-babel, bash

Is this possible? For example, determining the version of anaconda:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :results output
  conda -V | grep "conda"
#+END_SRC
```

If I remove the grep part I get no output at all, with it I at least get an Error Output window showing the conda version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done directly with bash:

```
 conda -V 2>&1 | grep "conda"
```